# How do I get the claims from an openid access token in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid, asp.net-core-2.0

My application authenticates using OpenId like this:

```c#
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
{
    o.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.Scope.Add("openid");
    o.Scope.Add("permissions");
    o.Authority = "https://localhost:44305";
    o.ClientId = "MyTestClient";
    o.ClientSecret = "MyTestClientSecret";
    o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken;
});
```

When I check the User object after authenticating, it only has claims from the ID token, not the access token. How do I get the claims from the access token?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you ever find a solution? Thanks

Comment: @MatthewChristianson nope :(

Comment: I've added an answer that worked for me. I could never get an access_token from OpenId

Answer (score 6):

You can use the OnTokenResponseReceived event from OpenIdConnectOptions.Events

```c#
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
{
    o.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.Scope.Add("openid");
    o.Scope.Add("permissions");
    o.Authority = "https://localhost:44305";
    o.ClientId = "MyTestClient";
    o.ClientSecret = "MyTestClientSecret";
    o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken;
    o.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {

        OnTokenResponseReceived = ctx =>
        {
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jsonToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(ctx.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);

            //jsonToken.Claims <--here you go, update the ctx.Principal if necessary.


            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: I note that this only works if the OIDC server is returning JWT access_tokens. OIDC does not require JWT to be used as they could also be "reference" (or "opaque") tokens which cannot be parsed to get Claims. So YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to intercept the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event from AddOpenIdConnect(). From there you should have access to  ctx.ProtocolMessage.Code which is the AuthorizationCode used with AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync() to generate further tokens. You also need to set ResponseType to "code id_token" in order that a code is also generated for you. A good tutorial for this is https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authenticatio. Hope this helps